# Change the boot time on macbook

Tags: boot, macbook, boot-time

First of all, I'm not an English speaker, sorry for any mistake you might come across.

I installed Ubuntu on an old macbook, and it actually runs great. The problem I have is that there is a waiting time on a white screen before it recognizes Ubuntu (once that happens everything goes by pretty quickly).

I tried changing the boot time using grub, but that made no difference whatsoever. I'm a linux newbie and would like some guidance as to how I can reduce the 'boot' time and if not, if there is a least a way as to how I can make it start silent

I've tried seeing other answers, but or they didn't work with me or I could not understand how to do them. It seems there is a way using a macOS disc or something alike, but I couldn't manage to do them.

Comment: Have you tried Zapping the PRAM?  Power the computer on, then hold down the Option+Command+P+R till you hear the chimes, then hold it down again a few times in a row.  I found that sometimes that helps.

Comment: but I would have to do it everytime or is there an input to make it always happen?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to.  What happens is over time the data in the PRAM can have issues, so you don't lose any data on your drives by doing this.

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't work :/

Comment: Maybe try installing the [rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html).  It might help!  Unfortunately as far as the Mac itself goes, there is not a lot of settings that you can change as far as boot time goes.